# Excel VBA - Code used to work, can't find the issue now

Tags: excel, vba

I was using this code and it was working just fine before, but now for some reason I'm getting an error that just says "400" and I didn't think I changed anything.

```
Sub getdata()

Dim xcell As Range
Dim ycell As Range
Dim sheetname As String
Dim wblist() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim wbname As String
Dim j As Integer

i = 0
j = 0

FolderName = "C:\Documents and Settings\shahzad.khan\Desktop\CRs\LOG"
wbname = Dir(FolderName & "\" & "*.xls")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While wbname <> ""

i = i + 1
ReDim Preserve wblist(1 To i)
wblist(i) = wbname
wbname = Dir


Set ycell = Range(Cells(i + 3, 2), Cells(i + 2, 28))
Set xcell = Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(2, 28))
sheetname = "loging form"

ycell.Formula = "=" & "'" & FolderName & "\[" & wblist(i) & "]" _
& sheetname & "'!" & xcell.Address

Loop

Do While j < 100
Cells(j + 3, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[6],4)"

Cells(3 + j, 1) = Val(Cells(3 + j, 1))
Cells(3 + j, 2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[CR Status.xlsx]Sheet1'!R3C1:R189C3,3,FALSE)"

If Cells(3 + j, 1).Value = 0 Then
Cells(3 + j, 1).Value = ""
Cells(3 + j, 2).Value = ""
End If

j = j + 1

Loop

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

I know the code isn't very efficient right now but it was working. It seems to be pasting most of the information I want but for some reason it's not capturing the first and last column from the excel files that I'm trying to pull from, and the second loop isn't even start. Also, its not accessing every file in the folder anymore, it seems to be stopping around 4 files before the end of the directory. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, is there some way of finding out?

Comment: Set breakpoints in the code, or use Step Into in the Debug menu.

Comment: I'm not sure how to set breakpoints, but i tried step into and it highlights my first loop, line by line.

Comment: Is there any reason that this would work one day but not another? Because it used to work fine all the time, but today it's just giving me issues.

Comment: Tell us on what line the error occurs. Then, maybe we can help.

Comment: I ran through the code and it looks like after going through 56 files it stops when it gets to the output line - ycell.formula...
So it never finishes the first loop.

Comment: Does anybody have any idea?
When I use a different directory that only has 5 files it seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

Error 400 corresponds to a Application-Defined or Object-Defined error. Which means it doesn't like or understand your reference to something usually.

Browsing through your code the only place that pops out is your

```
   Do While j < 100
   Cells(j + 3, 1).Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[6],4)"
```

Unless I missed it I dont see where you referenced what worksheet you're wanting it to loop through.

By the way you really should never have to "Select" a cell. It's slow and inefficient. Same with Worksheets. You can just do something similar to..

```
   Do While j < 100
   'First way
   Sheet1.Cells(J+3,1).FormulaR1C1 = "=Left(RC[6],4)"
   'Second way
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(J+3,1).FormulaR1C1 = "=Left(RC[6],4)"
```

Try to make sure all your references are explicitly set (Use f8 and loop through the code and watch the "Locals" window) and let me know if you have any problems, we'll narrow it down from there.

**EDIT:** Lets back this all the way up and tackle it from another point of view. What you need to do is go to Tools -> References -> and scroll down to Microsoft Scripting Runtime and click it and hit ok. Then use the following code.

```
Sub Main()
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
Dim File As File
Dim Folder As Folder
Dim Files As Files
Dim WkBook As Workbook
Dim FileInfo As Variant

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Documents and Settings\shahzad.khan\Desktop\CRs\LOG")
Set Files = Folder.Files

For Each File In Files

    If Right(File.Name, 3) = "xls" Then

    Set WkBook = Workbooks.Open(File)
    FileInfo = WkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:J400").Value

    'Do Work With Array Here

    WkBook.Close
    End If

Next

Set Files = Nothing
Set Folder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing


End Sub
```

Now, That code will work regardless of how many files you add or subtract. When you're done with working with the array and want to put the info into another excel sheet you can just flip the code around. Like...

```
MyWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A2:J400") = FileInfo
```

I know that doesn't answer the original question, but Error 400 usually ALWAYS means that something changed somewhere and now it can't find it. Rather than go looking for it, it's usually easier just to code in some protection.

Comment: thanks for the tip on selecting the cell.
Also, my code doesn't make it to the second loop, it seems like it's having trouble with the amount of files that are in the directory because it crashes before it's done pulling the info.

Comment: I used f8 to go through the loop and it looks like the error occurred at the "Ycell.formula" line. And it was after it pulled data from the 56 or 57th file.

Comment: Would it have something to do with me adding files? Because when I take a few files out and add new ones, it doesn't stop at the same place, it stops earlier.

Comment: I wanted to take the information from the files without actually having to open the files. It looks like this code opens and closes each one?

Comment: Any way you do it is going to "Open" the file anyways. You just might not see it in the foreground. You can use application.showwindowintaskbar = false, or/or application.screenupdating=false and you'll never see it happen. Just remember to set them to true late in the code. Or you could use ADODB to query the sheet. But thats something totally different and a longer explination.

Comment: The way I originally had the code was fine with me. I realize that it opens the file in some way, but it does it quickly without seeing the files open. 
Also, the files I'm using have macros running as well, so when the code tries to close them it prompts me whether I want to save or not, so I need to have it working the other way.

Comment: You can turn off or on the save prompts with Application.ThisWorkbook.Saved = True and/or
Application.DisplayAlerts = False. I'm not even sure how your original code worked, I've never seen anything done like that.